# How do I allow Django take in arbitrary URLs for usernames?

Tags: python, django, url, url-pattern

So basically I want to allow the user to go to mydomain.com/username and I have it working by adding this to the end of *urlpatterns*

```
(r'(?i)(?P<username>\w+)/$',user),
```

A potential issue I see arising is when a user has a username that matches with another pattern specified above. As unlikely as that could be, it's an edge case I want to catch and handle. I'm not sure what the best way to deal with it would be.

In **forms.py**, I have a custom username field that checks if the username is taken and that I can add other checks to. Would there be a way to basically add all the urls in urlpatterns to that list? Some way that it could automatically be changed as I add more, or would I have to hardcode them in?

Comment: Have you actually tried to see what would happen if you had a username that would collide with any pattern defined _before_ the username one?

Comment: It would just go to whatever view matched happened to match mydomain.com/username

Comment: I guess it would go to the first url pattern that has matched, so in this cause it would be the correct url, not the colliding one.

Comment: So there's no way to programmatically check urls? If not I might just give up on this...

Comment: What I meant is that, considering your urlpatterns looks like this: `(r'my_url/', view1), (r'my_url2/', view2), (r'(?i)(?P<username>\w+)/$',user),` then both _my_url_ and _my_url2_ will be matched __before__ your username url and in case of positive match, no further processing is done. So, in other words, if you put that url at the end of your `urlpatterns`, it will act as a url that will be matched if all other fail.